# Streamlit file_uploader - EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file, TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python, streamlit

I built a `streamlit` app where one can upload csv, xls, xlsx files.

And I'm loading the uploaded files using below functions `load_data`, `load_excel`

```
# Load dataset
@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def load_data(data_file):
    
    # Read csv using pandas
    data = pd.read_csv(data_file)
    # Copy dataframe
    df = data.copy()
    # return dataframe
    return df


@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def load_excel(data_file):
    
    # read excel using pandas
    exls = pd.read_excel(data_file, sheet_name=None)
    # make a copy of df
    xls = exls.copy()
    # extract sheet names to a list
    sheet_names = list(xls.keys())
    # return datframe & sheet names
    return xls, sheet_names
```

I'm using the below code to load the uploaded files. And it was working well.

```
data_file = st.file_uploader("Upload File",type=["csv", "xls", "xlsx"])

if data_file is not None:
    # cvs files only
    if data_file.name.endswith("csv"):

        # Read uploaded file
        raw_data = stu.load_data(data_file)

    else:
        # get excel and sheet names
        xls, sheet_names = stu.load_excel(data_file)
        # Dropdown to select sheet name
        sheet = st.selectbox("Select a Sheet", sheet_names)
        # Load selected sheet
        raw_data = xls[sheet]
```

This app is deployed in Domino. It was working fine. But from last couple of days its throwing an error for csv or xls files. The environment is not changed, and none of the libraries is updated/added. It's working fine in the local environment. Currently, I'm not sure what is causing this error or on how to fix this issue? Below is the complete `trace back` for xls and csv files. Can someone shed some light on what this issue is and how can fix this?

**Excel(xls) file traceback**

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 354, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/mnt/app.py", line 122, in <module>
    xls, sheet_names = stu.load_excel(data_file)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/streamlit/legacy_caching/caching.py", line 543, in wrapped_func
    return get_or_create_cached_value()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/streamlit/legacy_caching/caching.py", line 527, in get_or_create_cached_value
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/mnt/src/streamlit_utils.py", line 113, in load_excel
    exls = pd.read_excel(data_file, sheet_name=None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 867, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 351, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 35, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(file_contents=data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 110, in open_workbook
    filename = os.path.expanduser(filename)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 235, in expanduser
    path = os.fspath(path)
```

**CSV file traceback**

```
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 354, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/mnt/app.py", line 118, in <module>
    df = stu.load_data(data_file)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/streamlit/legacy_caching/caching.py", line 543, in wrapped_func
    return get_or_create_cached_value()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/streamlit/legacy_caching/caching.py", line 527, in get_or_create_cached_value
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/mnt/src/streamlit_utils.py", line 82, in load_data
    data = pd.read_csv(data_file)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 948, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1180, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2010, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 540, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
```

Comment: Try to disable the `st.cache` see what happens.